# GeoDjango Tutorial fails on model makemigrations command

Tags: python, django, geodjango, django-migrations

On Windows 7, the **GeoDjango** tutorial on Django's website, fails on the step where `WorldBorder` is migrated - that is the command:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

I get this popup:

> The procedure entry point `__gxx_personality_v0` could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll
>   (This is called from my python installation ..\Anaconda\Lib\cytypes\__init__.py)

And an error ouput:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import HAS_GEOS
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .libgeos import geos_version, geos_version_info  # NOQA: flake8 detects only the last __all__
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\libgeos.py", line 61, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\users\dev\Anaconda\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is the `libstdc++-6.dll` file in your `Anaconda\Scripts` folder?